# error ! failed to connect to 192.168.0.105(port7270) from /10.0.2.16(port 40622) after 86400000ms:

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, maui

error! failed to connect to 192.168.0.105(port7270) from /10.0.2.16(port 40622) after 86400000ms: isConnected failed ETMEOUT (connection timed out)

I get this problem when I press the button to get data from web API with app monkeys by the emulator.

please can you help me with how I can solve this problem?

this is the service?
MonkeyService:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace MonkeyFinder.Services;

public class MonkeyService
{
    HttpClient httpClient;

    public MonkeyService()
    {
        this.httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    }

    List<Monkey> monkeyList;

    
    public async Task<List<Monkey>> GetMonkeys()
    {
        if (monkeyList?.Count > 0)
            return monkeyList;
        
       // Online
       var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://192.168.0.105:7270/api/GetCust");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {  
            monkeyList = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Monkey>>();
        }

        return monkeyList;
    }
}
```

this is the ViewModel?

```
using MonkeyFinder.Services;

namespace MonkeyFinder.ViewModel;

public partial class MonkeysViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; } = new();
    MonkeyService monkeyService;
    public MonkeysViewModel(MonkeyService monkeyService)
    {
        Title = "Monkey Finder";
        this.monkeyService = monkeyService;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetMonkeysAsync()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var monkeys = await monkeyService.GetMonkeys();

            if(Monkeys.Count != 0)
                Monkeys.Clear();
                
            foreach(var monkey in monkeys)
                Monkeys.Add(monkey);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get monkeys: {ex.Message}");
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely a network issue, e.g. that port gets blocked by a firewall or your devices are in a different subnet.

Comment: but the firewall is off?

Comment: it's a connectivity problem, not a programming problem.  Verify connectivity to your server using your device's browser.  Do some basic network troubleshooting.  If you are using a local web server, be sure that it is configured to accept remote connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering one is on 10.* and the other is on 192.168.* there is a high probability that these are sitting on different networks or that one of the machines (or the network) is blocking that connection. These IP address ranges are both "private" IP address ranges and thus are sitting locally to the machines. So if one is indeed on another network, the connection is not actually trying to reach out to connect to the other because it can't "see" it.